# Querying SQL with four tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can someone explain me how to query these tables to get number of employees in companies for each country they are present in? Number of resulting columns should be 3, Company, Country and Employees. Company and Branch are connected but Country is connected with City so I am not sure how to solve this. Thanks guys, appreciate it!!!

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id         integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar NOT NULL,
  population integer check(population > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE city (
  id         integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar NOT NULL,
  population integer check(population > 0),
  country    integer NOT NULL REFERENCES country(id)
);

CREATE TABLE company (
  id         integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE branch (
  company    integer NOT NULL REFERENCES company(id),
  city       integer NOT NULL REFERENCES city(id),
  name       varchar,
  employees  integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (company, city)
);
```

This is what I did but I know it is wrong, I tried my combinations but so far nothing was correct!

```
SELECT 
branch.employees,
company.name AS company,
country.name AS country

FROM branch

INNER JOIN company 
ON branch.company = company.id

INNER JOIN country
ON city.country = country.id
ORDER BY country;
```

Comment: Learn about joins in sql.

Comment: When dealing with tough joins, I always start with a simple one. Get one down (say branch and company), then add more.

Comment: If you want to get the number of employes you will also need to use the sum function, togheter with the group by keyword

Comment: you almost got it, city table need to be joined before you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  company.name AS company,
  country.name AS country, 
  sum(branch.employees) AS country_employees
FROM branch
JOIN company ON company.id = branch.company
JOIN city ON city.id = branch.city
JOIN country ON country.id = city.country
GROUP BY company.name, country.name
ORDER BY country.name, company.name;
```

You want to sum over the number of employees per company, for each of the countries they work in. This means that you have to `GROUP BY` those two fields while you `SUM` the number employees per branch. You need to use the city table as well, even though you do not display any data from it.

Read up on aggregate functions for more background information.

Comment: thank you! I tried many online resources but most of them are basic ones...this explained a lot. thanks a bunch!